# Cannot use a boolean variable from another script Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have code that makes an object rotate, and its working ok if I call it from within the script.

ScriptA

```
public class ship : MonoBehaviour {
private bool toRotate=false;

    public void enemyRotate()
   {
         toRotate = true;
         Debug.Log("er "+ toRotate);
    }

 void Update () {
 if (toRotate)
        {

            transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.forward, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
}
```

If I call enemyRotate from within scriptA, sure enough I get the rotation, and the debug log shows the variable has been set to true. But if I call it from another function like this:

Script B

```
  public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {
      public ship ship_object;

      void Start(){

      ship_object=gameObject.AddComponent<kanaship> ();
      }

      void callFunction(){

      ship_object.enemyRotate()
      }

 }
```

If I call it from callFunction, I get the Debug log saying the variable has been set to true, BUT the rotation animation is not working at all. I have tried different variants of this but cannot figure out what Im doing wrong. I have even used a public bool and tried to set that to true from another script but nothing.

Comment: how does the `update()` method get invoked on the first example?

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to avoid accessing private vars (use Interface if necessary), but a better way is do declare function like following and to pass a proper boolean parameter:

```
 void Update (bool toRotate) {
 if (toRotate)
        {

            transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.forward, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
}
```

In this case, comment off the line:

```
//private bool toRotate=false;
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to rotate the gameobject that has the ScriptB attached or some other gameobject? Now your code adds the kanaship script to the gameobject that has the ScriptB and should rotate it. If you want to rotate some other game object you should find it, add the script and call the function e.g:

```
GameObject shipObject = GameObject.Find("EnemyShip").AddComponent<ship>().enemyRotate();
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out. I just needed to make toRotate static. Unreal.

Thanks if you tried to help me!